# Port DeflaterInputStream functionality to .net

Tags: java, c#, zip, sharpziplib

I am trying to port the following java code to .net:

```
private final byte[] zipLicense(byte lic[])
{
    byte buf[];
    ByteArrayInputStream bis;
    DeflaterInputStream dis;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
    buf = new byte[64];
    bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(lic);
    dis = new DeflaterInputStream(bis, new Deflater());
    bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte abyte0[];
    int len;
    while((len = dis.read(buf)) > 0) 
        bos.write(buf, 0, len);
    abyte0 = bos.toByteArray();
    try
    {
        bis.close();
        dis.close();
        bos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return abyte0;
}
```

My best shot was this code in C#:

```
private byte[] zipLicense(byte[] lic)
{
    var outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();

    ZipOutputStream zipStream;

    using (zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream))
    {
        zipStream.Write(lic, 0, lic.Length);
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Compressed bytes: {0}", outputMemStream.Length));
    }

    return outputMemStream.ToArray();
}
```

ZipOutputStream is a class from [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib)

When I try to run the C# code, I get error on first attempt to write to zipStream

```
zipStream.Write(lic, 0, lic.Length);
```

The error states that I haven't provided "No entry". I see in examples that one can and probably should seciffy an entry string to a zip stream, but what java code puts as an entry then? Please help in porting this java functionality to .Net. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java `DeflaterInputStream` is more like .NET's `DeflateStream`. That is, it's simply a compressed stream, without the directory index that a full .zip file would contain.

Try this:

```
private byte[] zipLicense(byte[] lic)
{
    var outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (DeflateStream stream =
        new DeflateStream(outputMemStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        stream.Write(lic, 0, lic.Length);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Compressed bytes: {0}", outputMemStream.Length));

    return outputMemStream.ToArray();
}
```

Note that I've added a call to `Flush()`. Without this, the `outputMemStream.Length` property may not be current (i.e. not quite the full length of the resulting stream).

For what it's worth, .NET now has reasonably good .zip file support built-in (e.g. `ZipArchive` class). So if you do find yourself actually needing that some day, I would try to use that first rather than adding a third-party library to your deployment.

Comment: Thank you for an elegant and native solution. Didn't find DefalteStream class when was looking for a C# alternative.

Comment: I double-checked, and realized that `Flush()` is a NOP here. Instead, you need to make sure `DeflateStream` doesn't dispose the underlying `MemoryStream`, and check the length after the `DeflateStream` is disposed. I've updated the code example to fix that issue.